# Swift TableViewController reuseIdentifier never works

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working in Swift with one `TableViewController` with one prototype cell. The cell has a reuse identifier specified in the storyboard, but it never dequeues properly. I always get the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

I've properly registered the class as follows:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myNewCell")
```

The offending code is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myNewCell") as UITableViewCell

    let textField = cell.viewWithTag(123) as UITextField
    textField.text = "test"

    return cell
}
```

I feel like I've tried everything here but it never properly gives a cell with that identifier. Even using the fallback (if nil, create a cell with that identifier) still gives the error. It's definitely having trouble getting a cell with that identifier, but it's registered and specified in the storyboard... Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing that the error is on the viewWithTag: line, since by registering the class, you're getting a default UITableViewCell that won't have a view with tag 123. Deleting that register method should fix the problem (Assuming that you set the cell's identifier to "myNewCell" in IB).

Comment: Wondering why you have override with cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Pretty sure that's a function in TableViewController, which I'm subclassing for my unique PrefixTableViewController. So it's an overridden method. Xcode inserted that keyword for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using cell prototypes, you do not call `registerClass`. The storyboard does that for you. If the cell prototype has its identifier specified, then just all  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`  and it should find your cell prototype without incident.

I'd suggest checking the spelling/capitalization of the identifier in storyboard and make sure it is identical to what is used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

---

I notice that you are trying to access a cell's label using a tag number. Nowadays, when dealing with custom cell layouts, we'd generally create our own table view subclass, e.g.:

```
//  CustomTableViewCell.swift

import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var customTextField: UITextField!    // note, I would use something other than textLabel to avoid confusion with base class

}
```

We'd then go to our cell prototype and specify its base class:

[image: cell base class]

We'd also set the cell prototype's identifier:

[image]

We'd then hook up the outlet between the cell prototype and our custom class `@IBOutlet`.

Having done all of that, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would be:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myNewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    cell.customTextField.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I confirmed that the identifier was correct, so I honestly have no idea what was going on. I wound up subclassing UITableViewCell and that fixed it.

Answer (score -4):

If dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is giving you problems then just don't use it.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
let cell = UITableViewCell()

let textField = cell.viewWithTag(123) as UITextField
textField.text = "test"

return cell
}
```

Comment: This is horrible, it completely by-passes the reuse queue and will impact performance on anything but trivial cells. And using tags to identify cells is a huge code smell.

Comment: Tags is from the asker, not me. This solution will work though, even if performance differs slightly.